# create css file with php

Tags: php, javascript, css

I need to create a dowloadable css file depending on variables changed on the front end.

Note: this is shortened example.

CSS:

`.color: red; width: incrementvalue();`

In html id have an inout field to adjust the width, example:

HTML

`<input type="text" value="3">`

Id then have a function that would run on change of the input that would do the following:

`$('input').on ('change', function (){return $(this).val () * 2});`

Yes the above function is in jquery but I dont really know php and im told this should be done in php.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you need it in PHP? I'd do it in PHP if the value needed to be saved somewhere (ex Database), but otherwise Jquery is the best solution.

Comment: It needs to create a downloadable css file, how can I do that with javascript/jquery? @Rov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a regular PHP file starting with a CSS header:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
```

After that, you can just echo out the CSS content. One way to do that is with heredoc syntax with a template system. The template puts variable values within '%%' percentage symbols as delimiters. Here's an example:

```
$css = <<<EOTAAA
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    background-color: %bg_color%;
    background-image: url(images/bg.gif);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    font:  14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
div.my_div{
    color: red;
    width: %width%;
}

EOTAAA;

$search = array('%bg_color%', '%width%');
$width = width_function();//some function for determining width
$bg_color = bg_function();//some function for determining background color
$replace = array($bg_color, $width);
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $css);
```

**Download Link:**

In your HTML, create a link something like this with the URL of the file that will handle the request:

```
<a href="HTTP://www.example.com/download.php">Get CSS</a>
```

And then in your PHP file, change the header information to the following:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"custom.css\"");
header('Content-type: text/css');
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Connection: close");
```

Comment: How would this create like a link for them to download though? So if I have a button that says download css, where would or how coukd I implement that?

Comment: So this would create a download.css file? I dont want them to download a php file, sorry if im confused

Comment: It's a PHP file that produces a CSS file. Look at the filename in the header function: "custom.css." You can change that to whatever you like.

Comment: It worked brilliantly, although now that I've learnt this, I may have to revisit, because I need the download button to actually download a few files at once, which I'd like to zip them up etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?php
   header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
   $my_width= incrementvalue();
?>

.phpClass{color: red; width: <?php echo $my_width;?>}
```

Save this file as `style.php`

**Usage**

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.php' />
```

Read http://css-tricks.com/css-variables-with-php/

Comment: But this would be a php file that they wuld download right not css?

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are binding change event. That probably means you want to change width dynamically. You can not script on client-side using PHP. PHP is server language which is useless in this case. If you want to change something dynamically, you have to use client scripting. jQuery (or Knockour.JS) is probably the easiest solution.

Comment: Sorry I did write that a little weird, jquery will update the ui on the page,  kind of like a demo of what they will be downloading, but there will be a button that would generate a file using this information for them to download when the click said button

Answer (score 0):

1. You'd better increase width of the input box with javascript. Using PHP will definitely increase network load - the web browser should send request for each change of input box.
2. If you really need to refresh of stylesheet, `<link id='dynamic_stylesheet' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='style.php?length=3' />` and later change href of `$('#dynamic_stylesheet')`. In this case, you'd better just load extra styles of different selectors and change the class of input tag later.
3. jQuery event callback function should return a boolean value representing whether it overrides the pre-defined behavior.

Comment: I do want it to be a css file though not a css file that they download?